# JTable row limitation

Tags: swing, jtable, java

I have to limit the number of rows in a `JTable`.  If I have 100 records I need to display 10 on the initial loading of JTable.  I wish to put a button like `"next"`, and after each click it shows another set of 10 records.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I have to limit the number of rows in a JTable.  If i have 100 records i need to display 10 on the initial loading of JTable.

Use preferred size (+ an appropriate layout and layout constraint) to fix the size.

> I wish to put a button like "next", and after each click it showing another set of 10 records.

Remove the scroll bar on the RHS of the scroll pane.  Then use buttons instead for the effect of 'next/previous'.

### Like this

[image: Pageable table]

### FixedRowsTable.java

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

class FixedRowsTable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                String[] columns = {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7"};
                Integer[][] data = new Integer[1000][columns.length];
                for (int xx=0; xx<data.length; xx++) {
                    for (int yy=0; yy<data[0].length; yy++) {
                        data[xx][yy] = new Integer((xx+1)*(yy+1));
                    }
                }
                final int rows = 11;

                JPanel gui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(3,3));

                final JTable table = new JTable(
                    new DefaultTableModel(data, columns));

                final JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(
                    table,
                    JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER,
                    JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
                Dimension d = table.getPreferredSize();
                scrollPane.setPreferredSize(
                    new Dimension(d.width,table.getRowHeight()*rows));

                JPanel navigation = new JPanel(
                    new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
                JButton next = new JButton(">");
                next.addActionListener( new ActionListener(){
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                        int height = table.getRowHeight()*(rows-1);
                        JScrollBar bar = scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar();
                        bar.setValue( bar.getValue()+height );
                    }
                } );
                JButton previous = new JButton("<");
                previous.addActionListener( new ActionListener(){
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                        int height = table.getRowHeight()*(rows-1);
                        JScrollBar bar = scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar();
                        bar.setValue( bar.getValue()-height );
                    }
                } );

                navigation.add(previous);
                navigation.add(next);

                gui.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                gui.add(navigation, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, gui);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure this is what the OP wants, here you just limit the number of visible rows, but the model holds **all** rows. I think the OP wants a pagination system instead.

Comment: Hi my table contains more than 1000 records. So I need to view all records without a scrollbar.So if i have 1000 records first showing 1 to 10 records.If i click "next" button it will show 11 to 20 and so on.Hope you are clear abt my question now ? plz help me to find a soultion.

Comment: I've the same problem and I can't fix the trouble with this solution. You set a preferredSize for the table and then add it in the panel in the center. But I know that BorderLayout.CENTER ignores the preferred sizes of its components. Could you tell me where I'm wrong?

Comment: @user2896152 *"Could you tell me where I'm wrong?"*  Could you ask a new question?  If you do, include an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Answer (score 2):

If you use an [AbstractTableModel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) you can display millions of records. The idea is that your model will be loading whatever records are needed for the view, on demand.

Here you have such a Model. It's not my best code, but will do :-) ...

```
public class SomeTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    public SomeTableModel(ResultSet rs) {
        this.rs = rs;
        try {
            pos = this.rs.getRow();
            System.out.println(String.valueOf(pos));
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
        }

    }

    public int getRowCount() {
        int cnt = 0;
        int apos = 0;
        try {
            apos = rs.getRow();
            rs.last();
            cnt = rs.getRow();
            if (apos > 0)
                rs.absolute(apos);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("getRowCount: " + ex);
        }

        return cnt;
    }

    public int getColumnCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        // make it jump back to pos !!
        Object val = null;
        Integer intVal;

        try {
            if (rowIndex == 0) {
                pos = rs.getRow();
                total = getRowCount();
            }
            rs.absolute(rowIndex + 1);
            switch (columnIndex) {
                case 0: intVal = rs.getInt(1); val = intVal; break;
                case 1: val = rs.getString(2); break;
                case 2: val = rs.getString(3); break;
                default: val = "error";
            }
            rs.absolute(pos);
        } catch (SQLException sqle) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Trouble in model");
        }
        return val;
    }

    private ResultSet rs;
    private int pos, total;
}
```

Comment: Add it like this: "jTable1.setModel(new SomeTableModel(rs));" rs is the ResultSet.

Answer (score 1):

If you are loading the data from a database table, I think the best way to go is to limit the data coming from the database. Then apply a simple algorithm for the next and previous buttons.

Comment: Ya its loading from database table.But i wish to avoid query calling on each click . I think thats help to improve my application performance.Let me know ur suggestions regarding this ?