# Java: JTable allows only 100 rows

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I want to insert the data of the hash map in my JTable .So, it may require more than 100 rows but JTable (i am using Drag and Drop Netbeans GUI) properties don't allows me to exceed the number of rows more than 100.What to do?Following is the code

```
              HashMap<String, KnownFlows> b=  d.FlowAnalyzer();
            for (int i = 1; i <= b.size(); i++) {
        String key = Integer.toString(i);
           jTable1.getModel().setValueAt(b.get(key).date,i, 0);
           jTable1.getModel().setValueAt(b.get(key).month,i, 1);
           jTable1.getModel().setValueAt(b.get(key).time,i, 2);
          }
```

Comment: What does drag and drop have to do with populating a `JTable` from a hash map?

Comment: A JTable definitely allows more than 100 rows. There is something you are not telling us.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  Didn't get u? I guess i have written everything which i have done uptill now :S

Comment: @Zara The `JTable` component can handle large number of rows, without problems. We are asking you to show us your code, to understand how you fill your table...

Comment: See also [JTable row limitation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6175860/418556).

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you to use the method "addRow" of DefaultTableModel.
I think your tableModel has a limit of row of 100.

Answer (score 0):

```
DefaultTableModel dm = (DefaultTableModel ) jtable.getModel();

dm.setRowCount(0);

Object[] rowdata = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6};

dm.addRow(rowdata);

jtable.setModel(dm);
```