# Limit rows shown in JTable + Next/Previous button

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I'm trying to create a JTable that's only showing one row at the time. When you press Next/Previous, the table will display either the next or the previous row, depending on the button pressed. If there is no Next/Previous, the JTable shall display the first/last element.

Code for only showing one row at a time:

```
tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
tableModel.setRowCount(0); //If I remove this, the things I add ends up att the 2nd line.
tableModel.addTableModelListener(resultTable);
resultTable = new JTable(tableModel);
scroll = new JScrollPane(resultTable, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);

final int rows = 1;
Dimension d = resultTable.getPreferredSize();
resultTable.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(d.width,resultTable.getRowHeight()*rows));
```

Code for Next-button (Not working, what do to? Shows the same element as before):

```
int height = resultTable.getRowHeight()*(rows-1);
JScrollBar bar = scroll.getVerticalScrollBar();
bar.setValue( bar.getValue()+height);
```

Code for Previous-button (Not working, same as above, nothing happens/changes.)

```
int height = resultTable.getRowHeight()*(rows-1);
JScrollBar bar = scroll.getVerticalScrollBar();
bar.setValue(bar.getValue()-height);
```

What do to? Some help would be greatly appreciated. Been trying to solve this forever.

Edit: Trying to follow the code from here: [JTable row limitation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6175139/jtable-row-limitation) but can't get it to work.. Though I only want to show 1 row, not 10.

Comment: are you sure you want a table here?

Comment: Table or not doesn't really matter. Just seemed to be an easy way to do it. What would be a better way of doing it?

Comment: Did you change tableModel? Jtable here is only represents model data.

Comment: Nope, didn't change tableModel.

Answer (score 0):

From the above you specify row count to get single row in a table

```
 final int rows = 2;
```

Alternatively you could try with table with Row header. Here is a sample
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/TableRowHeaderExample.htm

Comment: Changing int rows to 2 only makes it possible to show 2 rows at a time. Gonna check row header out later, thanks :)