# Dynamically loading large amount of data in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Here is my problem: I currently have a JTable containing anywhere from
5,000 to well over 200,000 rows. You see where I'm going with this.
The data is already loaded into memory, which isn't a problem, but how
can I create an efficient JTable so that it only loads the rows that
are visible and that any events only act on those rows that are
visible in the viewport? Obviously scrolling is nearly impossible with
this much data, as it takes forever for the system to repaint and fire
events.

Basically I think one solution would be to determine which rows are in
the viewport, then create a new model containing those rows perhaps?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might use a [`FixedRowsTable`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6175860/418556) type design, here showing some of 200,000 rows. Though you'd want to add extra buttons  <kbd><<</kbd> <kbd>>></kbd>

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

class FixedRowsTable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                String[] columns = {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7"};
                Integer[][] data = new Integer[200000][columns.length];
                for (int xx=0; xx<data.length; xx++) {
                    for (int yy=0; yy<data[0].length; yy++) {
                        data[xx][yy] = new Integer((xx+1)*(yy+1));
                    }
                }
                final int rows = 11;

                JPanel gui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(3,3));

                final JTable table = new JTable(
                    new DefaultTableModel(data, columns));

                final JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(
                    table,
                    JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER,
                    JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
                Dimension d = table.getPreferredSize();
                scrollPane.setPreferredSize(
                    new Dimension(d.width,table.getRowHeight()*rows));

                JPanel navigation = new JPanel(
                    new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
                JButton next = new JButton(">");
                next.addActionListener( new ActionListener(){
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                        int height = table.getRowHeight()*(rows-1);
                        JScrollBar bar = scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar();
                        bar.setValue( bar.getValue()+height );
                    }
                } );
                JButton previous = new JButton("<");
                previous.addActionListener( new ActionListener(){
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                        int height = table.getRowHeight()*(rows-1);
                        JScrollBar bar = scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar();
                        bar.setValue( bar.getValue()-height );
                    }
                } );

                navigation.add(previous);
                navigation.add(next);

                gui.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                gui.add(navigation, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, gui);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: actually my problem is when i add large amount of data,JDialog will take more time to be open? can i solve with this?

Comment: *"JDialog will take more time to be open?"*  The code above opens with 200,000 rows with no noticeable delay.  How long does ..500,000 take?  How long does it take with your actual objects in a 'large group'?  Test these things before presuming it will be too slow.

Comment: The problem is when i load the table with contents from sql database

Comment: @Nikhil The problems then comes from you SQL query on your DB and not from the JTable itself. You could restrict the number of fetch data. Also, make sure to move the query outside the EDT, using a SwingWorker for example.

Comment: @Nikhil have look at Pagination on SQL side, by default no issue with performance, for larger table there is issue with 1st. query only, rest is returned very quickly