# How to set row size of JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I'm going to create application 
in that to enter invoice i've created form in which i have used JTable
but end user requirement is that the the description may be of 2 to 3 lines 
(image of table)
[i![]]

so i want the code to increase the size of row

Comment: See [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6175860/418556).  By the way.  ITYM 'number' of rows either 2 or 3, rather than 'size' of each row.  Also, the image is missing.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> end user requirement is that the the description may be of
>   2 to 3 lines

I assume that you are trying to display data in multiple lines in a `JTable` cell. An example which I have tried to show data in multiple lines within a cell.

As @Sergii has suggested use `JTable.setRowHeight` to increase the height of the cell. The `data column` cell is rendered with `JTextArea`.

[image: JTable with a cell rendered as JTextArea]

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.util.EventObject;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.event.CellEditorListener;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellEditor;


public class JTableCellTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Object[] columnNames = {"S.No", "Data"};
                Object[][] data = {
                                        {"1", "I'm going to create application in that to enter invoice i've created form in which i have used JTable but end user requirement is that the the description may be of 2 to 3 lines.\n I'm going to create application in that to enter invoice i've created form in which i have used JTable but end user requirement is that the the description may be of 2 to 3 lines. \n I'm going to create application in that to enter invoice i've created form in which i have used JTable but end user requirement is that the the description may be of 2 to 3 lines"},
                                        {"2", "I'm going to create application in that to enter invoice i've created form in which i have used JTable but end user requirement is that the the description may be of 2 to 3 lines.\n I'm going to create application in that to enter invoice i've created form in which i have used JTable but end user requirement is that the the description may be of 2 to 3 lines. \n I'm going to create application in that to enter invoice i've created form in which i have used JTable but end user requirement is that the the description may be of 2 to 3 lines"},
                                        {"3", "I'm going to create application in that to enter invoice i've created form in which i have used JTable but end user requirement is that the the description may be of 2 to 3 lines.\n I'm going to create application in that to enter invoice i've created form in which i have used JTable but end user requirement is that the the description may be of 2 to 3 lines. \n I'm going to create application in that to enter invoice i've created form in which i have used JTable but end user requirement is that the the description may be of 2 to 3 lines"}
                                  };

                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames);
                table.setRowHeight(70);

                table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setCellRenderer(new CustomCellRenderer());
                table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setCellEditor(new CustomEditor());

                frame.setTitle("JTable with JTextArea");
                frame.add(new JScrollPane(table));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);

            }
        };

        EventQueue.invokeLater(r);
    }
}

class CustomCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

        private JTextArea textArea;
        private JScrollPane scrollPane;

        public CustomCellRenderer() {
            textArea = new JTextArea();
            scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
        }

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
                boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {

            if(null != value)
                textArea.setText(value.toString());

            return scrollPane;
        }
}

class CustomEditor implements TableCellEditor {

    private JTextArea textArea;
    private JScrollPane scrollPane;

    public CustomEditor() {
        textArea = new JTextArea();
        scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value,
            boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
        if(null != value)
            textArea.setText(value.toString());

        return scrollPane;
    }

    @Override
    public void addCellEditorListener(CellEditorListener arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void cancelCellEditing() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public Object getCellEditorValue() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return textArea.getText();
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(EventObject arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public void removeCellEditorListener(CellEditorListener arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public boolean shouldSelectCell(EventObject arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean stopCellEditing() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: thankx sir, i want the method by which  if client entering text then after specific no of words or length of word the curser automatically gose to next line

Answer (score 6):

- `JTable->TableColumnModel->TableColum` (change size of column, and
  just investigate editor and render)
- `JTable-setRowHeight` (change height of row)