# Need jTable to show 10 rows after time delay then load new records after all displayed

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, event-handling, jtable

**SOLVED and EDITED with Working Version and left in case it can help someone else**

The Rows of this jTable are being populated from a 2D String Array.  The array will be dynamic.  I need to only display 10 rows for 3 seconds, then display another 10 rows for 3 seconds, repeat this cycle until end of array then refill array and start cycle again.

I can't find any examples of jTables using time delay to update table instead of buttons, data change etc.
**EDIT** - Fixed the rows to display with Timer ActionListener

The rows to display will be selected from a jSpinner also but how can I implement the set Rows instead of showing all rows?  Vertical and Horizontal scrolling is disabled in the jScrollPane.

**EDIT** - I am still stuck on how to "refill" and display the new records after displaying all records in my array 1 first time through..**SOLVED with another Timer/ActionListener and new DefaultTableModel**

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class DataTable2 {

String [][] data;       //2D Array (MultiDimensional) for Records.
String [] titles;       //Array for ColumnTitles
JTable table;           
DefaultTableModel model;
JScrollPane pane;       
JFrame frame;           
JPanel panel;  


public DataTable2(int rows, int radio){
    //Fill Arrays.
    titles = setTitles2(radio);
    data = fill2();
    //Timer Variables.
    final int SPEED = 4000;//3.5 sec delay for displaying number of rows on screen.
    int pause = 1000;
    //Row Variable
    final int R=rows;//For Timer ActionListener.

    //Components
    frame = new JFrame("Live Table");
    panel = new JPanel();
    model = new DefaultTableModel(data, titles);
    table = new JTable(model){
                @Override
                public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int colIndex){
                    return false;
                }};
    pane = new JScrollPane(table, ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER,
    ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);

    //Table Formatting...More Done but not shown in example to keep shorter.
    table.setRowHeight(100);
    table.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD,24));
    table.getTableHeader().setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 24));

    //Modified Code derived from FixedRowsTable  <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6175139/jtable-row-limitation> by @Andrew Thompson
    //To show set number of rows of the table at a time. eg. 10 rows, timer, 10 rows,  timer etc......
    Dimension d = table.getPreferredSize();
    Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    pane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(screenSize.width-50, table.getRowHeight()*rows));

    //Set as constants to be accessed by both ActionListeners.
    final int HEIGHT = table.getRowHeight()*(R);
    final JScrollBar BAR = pane.getVerticalScrollBar();
    //Listener for Timer. 
    ActionListener perform = new ActionListener(){
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        BAR.setValue(BAR.getValue()+HEIGHT);
        }
    };
    //Listener for Timer 2.
    ActionListener update = new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
            BAR.setValue(0);//Reset Row Height.
            DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, titles);             
            table.setModel(model);
            }
    };

    //Timer.
    Timer timer = new Timer(SPEED, perform);
    timer.setRepeats(true);
    timer.start();

    //Timer 2.
    double val = table.getRowCount();///R;
    int time = 0;
    //Formula to compensate for SwingTimer accepting only Integer Values.
    if(val%R!=0){
      time=SPEED;  
    }
    time+= (table.getRowCount()/R)*SPEED;

    //Timer 2
    Timer timer2 = new Timer(time, update);
    timer2.setRepeats(true);
    timer2.start();

    //Debug
    System.out.println(time);
    System.out.println(val);
    System.out.println(val%R);

    //Set Panel to Full Screen
    panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension (screenSize.width,screenSize.height));
    //Add Components.
    frame.add(panel);
    panel.add(pane);
//Frame Close Operation.
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    //Table Constraints.
    table.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);
    table.getTableHeader().setResizingAllowed(true);
    table.setShowVerticalLines(false);
    table.setShowHorizontalLines(true);
//Apply Model to Table
    table.setModel(model);
    //Add table to scroll pane.
    pane.setViewportView(table);
    //Finish Frame
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationByPlatform(false);
    frame.setVisible(true); 
}   
/**
 * Method to fill table with String values for testing outside of network.
 * @return String array of Records.
 */
private String[][] fill2(){
        String[][] temp = {{"Record1", "Record2", "Record3", "Record4", "Record5", "Record6"},
                        {"Record7", "Record8", "Record9", "Record10", "Record11", "Record12"},
                        {"Record13", "Record14", "Record15", "Record16", "Record17", "Record18"},
                        {"Record19", "Record20", "Record21", "Record22", "Record23", "Record24"},
                        {"Record25", "Record26", "Record27", "Record28", "Record29", "Record30"},
                        {"Record31", "Record32", "Record33", "Record34", "Record35", "Record36"},
                        {"Record37", "Record38", "Record39", "Record40", "Record41", "Record42"},
                        {"Record43", "Record44", "Record45", "Record46", "Record47", "Record48"},
                        {"Record49", "Record50", "Record51", "Record52", "Record53", "Record54"},
                        {"Record55", "Record56", "Record57", "Record58", "Record59", "Record60"},
                        {"Record61", "Record62", "Record63", "Record64", "Record65", "Record66"},
                        {"Record67", "Record68", "Record69", "Record70", "Record71", "Record72"},
                        {"Record73", "Record74", "Record75", "Record76", "Record77", "Record78"},
        };
        return temp;
}

/**
 * Method to fill String array of column titles.
 * @param rad jRadioButton value from buttonGroup sent from main settings frame.
 * @return Column Titles
 */
private String[] setTitles2(int rad){
        String[] t;

        if(rad==2){
                t = new String[]{"TITLE1", "TITLE2"};
        }else if(rad==5||rad==10){
                t = new String[]{"TITLE1", "TITLE2", "TITLE3", "TITLE4", "TITLE5", "TITLE6", "TITLE7", "TITLE8"};
        }else if(rad==6){
                t = new String[]{"TITLE1", "TITLE2"};
        }else if(rad==7){
                t = new String[]{"TITLE1"};
        }else if(rad==8||rad==9){
                t = new String[]{"TITLE1", "TITLE2", "TITLE3", "TITLE4", "TITLE5"};
        }else{
                t=new String []{"TITLE1", "TITLE2", "TITLE3", "TITLE4", "TITLE5", "TITLE6"};
        }
return t;
}

//Main sample just to show table.
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Sample Value for Example.
    int x = 10;  //Any Value from 1-10 will be used. 5 or 10 will be used most reguarly.
    int y = 1;  //Any Value from 1-9 will be used.  1 will be used most reguarly.
    //Call Table.
    DataTable2 table = new DataTable2(x,y);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a [javax.swing.Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html), and in its `actionPerformed()` method, get the next 10 rows to display, and replace the rows in the model of the table by those next 10 rows.

Comment: Got the Timer to show the selected rows, but still stuck on how to reload the array i'm using to fill the table.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding another Timer and ActionListener, formula for time it will take to display all rows, reset the height of the ScrollBar while making the height and bar finals to be accessed by both ActionListeners, and then creating a new DefaultTableModel and using the setModel() method.

```
//Section Edited to Fix.
final int HEIGHT = table.getRowHeight()*(R);
    final JScrollBar BAR = pane.getVerticalScrollBar();
    //Listener for Timer. 
    ActionListener perform = new ActionListener(){
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        BAR.setValue(BAR.getValue()+HEIGHT);
        }
    };
    //Listener for Timer 2.
    ActionListener update = new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
            BAR.setValue(0);
            DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, titles);             
            table.setModel(model);
            }
    };

    //Timer.
    Timer timer = new Timer(SPEED, perform);
    timer.setRepeats(true);
    timer.start();
    //Timer 2.
    double val = table.getRowCount();///R;
    int time = 0;
    if(val%R!=0){
      time=SPEED;  
    }
    time+= (table.getRowCount()/R)*SPEED;
    Timer timer2 = new Timer(time, update);
    timer2.setInitialDelay(time);
    timer2.setRepeats(true);
    timer2.start();
```

I wish to leave this question up in the hope that it will help someone else with updating a JTable using a timer instead of the standard TableListeners.  I am also editing the question to show the final code.

PS> I Understand the JTable is refreshing a little off with the rows and timing but that is a seperate issue that I am now working on.  I will post an edit when it is fixed.

Thank You JB Nizet (for some reason it will not let me tag you) for the Timer ActionListener recommendation.